# Set property validation message at class level

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using a class level ValidationAttribute to compare two date objects (looking for one greater than the other) using (equivalent of):

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection greaterprop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        object greatervalue = greaterprop.Find(GreaterProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
```

I can compare the objects fine, and return false from isValid, but I can only set the validation message at class level.  This means that if I have more than one class level custom attribute, then the validation error message will appear wherever I set

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => this.Model.ClassName )%>
```

If it's a big form, then the user will have to search for the point it is referring to (since I can't put it next to a section as there is more than one class level ValidationAttribute - would result in error messages appearing at wrong section) .

I'm wondering if there is some sort of way to set a property's validation error message from the class level ValidationAttribute (so validation message appears where I want).

I'm using MVC2.

Comment: OK - since no-one else has posted - I've been looking at a way around this. I was wondering if I could use the property's attribute collection to fire an isValid false one a specifically created attribute to cause an invalid model state.  Can't get this to work though, as class level attribute validation comes after property...